# Unable to install NVidia drivers - "trying to overwrite... which is also in"

Tags: apt, nvidia, package-management

While trying to install drivers for my NVidia 1050M, I had an issue with overwriting a file created by another package.

```
~$ sudo apt-get install nvidia-390
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libbsd0:i386 libffi6:i386 libgl1:i386 libglvnd0:i386 libglx0:i386 libnvidia-cfg1-390 libnvidia-fbc1-390 libnvidia-fbc1-390:i386 libnvidia-gl-390:i386
  libnvidia-ifr1-390 libnvidia-ifr1-390:i386 libwayland-client0:i386 libwayland-server0:i386 libx11-6:i386 libxau6:i386 libxcb1:i386 libxdmcp6:i386
  libxext6:i386 nvidia-dkms-390 nvidia-kernel-common-390 nvidia-kernel-source-390
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  nvidia-390
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
113 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/76.5 MB of archives.
After this operation, 308 MB of additional disk space will be used.
(Reading database ... 142258 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../nvidia-390_390.30-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking nvidia-390 (390.30-0ubuntu1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/nvidia-390_390.30-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/lib/udev/rules.d/71-nvidia.rules', which is also in package nvidia-kernel-common-390 390.48-0ubuntu3
dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/nvidia-390_390.30-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I don't know where to go from here. Can anyone provide help? I am dual-booting with Windows 10 and have had no problems until trying to install these NVidia drivers.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Could you please [edit] your question to include the output of `lsb_release -a` and `apt-cache policy nvidia-390 nvidia-kernel-common-390`? Thanks.